# Generating reports from Nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios

Are there any good plugins for generating reports from Nagios like CPU, Memory usage over a month and so on.

I am already using Nagiosgraph. Any way export the data for month, year and so on?

Answer (score 1):

you'd better run icinga (nagios-fork) and the run jasper-server and jasper-reports.

the new icinga-builds will have [jasper-reports](http://www.netways.de/en/de/produkte/icinga/aufbau_features/reports/) included

anything else looks like a terrible hack imho.

simple reports are available though nagios-webinterface like monthly availability report, up/downtime in percentage etc.